# Pivoting Undefined Text Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I have 2 tables of data that I need to join together in a SQL Server query - one with transaction information, and one with marketing questions that have been answered for a transaction.

Here is a stripped-down example:

```
 -------------------------------------------
|              Transaction Info             |
|-------------------------------------------|
|Transaction_ID  |Date          |Customer_ID|
|1               |2016-01-01    |2614       |
|2               |2016-04-16    |3981       |
|3               |2016-06-25    |2113       |
 -------------------------------------------

 ------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   Marketing Questions                            |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Transaction_ID  |Question                             |Answer     |
|1               |How would you rate our service?      |Excellent  |
|2               |Would you recommend us?              |Yes        |
|2               |Where did you hear about us?         |Friend     |
|1               |Any other comments?                  |None       |
|3               |How would you rate our service?      |Average    |
|2               |Any other comments?                  |None       |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's where I'm stuck: I need to pivot the questions in the marketing table to become column names in the final joined table, where the cell value is the answer.

The problem is that the questions are randomized from a very large set, and so I cannot define them in the query. It needs to dynamically capture all the questions that have been returned in the table, generate them as columns, and populate the answers in the cells.

The marketing table is itself the result of a date-ranged query, and so the questions included will not always be the same. This is why I can't just define them in a PIVOT ahead of time.

I really don't know where to start with this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ouch...it looks like your MarketingQuestions is in serious need of normalization. Repeating the questions over and over is not the best design. That being said, what you are trying accomplish sounds like a dynamic pivot. It has been asked and answered around here hundreds and hundreds of times.

Comment: I did something recently using recursive ctes. I would need to see be at a computer to write up there code and test but yeah tour in for a little pain

Comment: If the application ends up being 10% DBMS code and 90% supporting code intended to address the deficiencies in the DBMS functionality, then either (a) choose a different DBMS or (b) don't use a DBMS in the first place.  DBMS is intended to make the task SIMPLER, not MORE COMPLICATED.  If it ain't, then it's clearly inappropriate and unsuited to the task at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using dynamic SQL.  For Example:

```
DECLARE @dynPiv varchar(max)
DECLARE @PivotQuery

SET @dynPiv = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Question)
                    FROM MarketingQuestions
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

SET @PivotQuery = '[YOUR QUERY HERE]
PIVOT ( [YOUR PIVOT GOES HERE] FOR Question IN ' + @dynPiv + ')'
```

Didnt type out the whole code but that should communitcate the idea.  The @dynPiv will take the value of all distinct values for Question.  Print @dynPiv for a better visualization

Answer (score 0):

Once again, PIVOT is great, but I use a stored procedure for Dynamic Pivots

Not sure on your desired output, but you can play with the parameters/group by's

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Question
      ,B.Answer
 Into #Temp
 From Transction A
 Join Marteting B
   on (A.Transaction_ID=B.Transaction_ID)

Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Question','max(Answer)[]','Customer_ID,Transaction_ID,Date','count(*)[Records]'
```

Returns

[image]

The Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

--Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select Year=Year(TR_Date),* From [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','''Q''+DateName(QQ,TR_Date)','avg(TR_Y10)[-Avg]','Year','count(*)[Records],min(TR_Y10)[Min],max(TR_Y10)[Max],Avg(TR_Y10)[Avg]'
--Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Attribute','max(Description)[]','ID','count(*)[Records]'

Set NoCount On
Set Ansi_Warnings Off

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),0) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)


Set NoCount Off
Set Ansi_Warnings on
```

Comment: @Merenix  Going to keep it my clipboard

Comment: definately. Its an interestimg solution.   I got a quick question though So let's say I work in an organization that will only allow data-Reader access. What you recommend. So far I have done ctes and pivoted back but  yeah I usually just cry under a desk and hope the problem goes away

Comment: It is an interesting solution but I don't like setting ANSI_WARNINGS off. This allows for silent truncation which could be very bad.

Comment: @Merenix Interesting question.  The source can be SQL, and datareader can get rights to a stored procedure.  Other than that you would have to go pure dynamic

Comment: @SeanLange True, but I haven't witnessed any issues to date.  That said, I just may remove it.  Even though I am very comfortable being "Fat, Dumb, and Happy", I think I'd rather know if there was an issue.   Thanks for the tip

Comment: Thought as much sadly if we can't get things added except the data already present getting a stored procedure in would be downright amazing.

Comment: @Merenix Must be incredibly frustrating working with your hands tied behind your back

Comment: No joke i'm 28 and gone from no greys to a full set in a year.